# htaccess redirect rules combination

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I want to redirect from

> http -> https

and

> without www -> with www

via htacess file.

I need both in combination in one htacess file.

How are the rewrite rules for this combination? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is use this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

It checks if `www` and `HTTPs` are enabled. If not, it forces them both to on.

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

EDIT: Try this.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: It seems to work now. THANK YOU VERY MUCH.  (without /, please change your edit)

Comment: I am using Let's encrypt https://letsencrypt.org/  for https, it's free.

Comment: Somebody remove more than 10 comments here!